# Lines on blowups of the projective plane or Hirzebruch surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Are there any references which discuss material relevant to lines on rational surfaces other than del Pezzo surfaces? It is entirely possible that I'm missing some fundamental/important facts which  explain why all the references I've seen only discuss del Pezzo surfaces.

I understand that there are infinitely many $(-1)$-curves on blowups of $\mathbb{P}^2$ at $\ge 9$ points (in general position), but this doesn't seem to be enough since the fact that $(-1)$-curves on blowups at a smaller number of points correspond to lines on del Pezzo surfaces depends on properties of the anticanonical embedding. On the other hand, I'm not sure what is a good way of analyzing blowups of Hirzebruch surfaces.

**Second edit addressing questions in the comments:**

In this question, we're fixing a particular embedding $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$. (Side question: Is there a particular natural embedding of $\text{Bl}_{p_1, \ldots, p_n} \mathbb{P}^2$ into projective space like the canonical embedding of del Pezzo surfaces?)

By a "line" on $\text{Bl}_{p_1, \ldots, p_n} \mathbb{P}^2$, we mean the class of a curve $C$ in $\text{Pic } X$ such that $C \cdot H = 1$ with $H$ being the class of a hyperplane in $\mathbb{P}^n$.

For blowups of Hirzebruch surfaces $\Sigma$, we'll look at pullbacks of lines on Hirzebruch surfaces assuming an embedding $\Sigma \subset \mathbb{P}^N$ for some $N$.

Comment: What polarization do you consider (to make sense of speaking of lines)?

Comment: If I understood your question correctly: I didn't have a particular embedding into a projective space in mind (just that we fixed one), but one possibility I had thought about was embedding of the (projective) rational surface $X$ into $\mathbb{P}^n$ for the smallest $n$ possible. We can also consider a different $n$ if there is a more ``natural'' embedding (e.g. when $X$ is a blowup of $\mathbb{P}^2$).

Comment: In fact, my question is, what do you mean by a line?

Comment: I was thinking about the class in $\text{Pic } X$ of a pullback of a line in $\mathbb{P}^2$ not passing through the points we're blowing up like del Pezzo surfaces or a class $C$ in $\text{Pic } X$ such that $C \cdot H = 1$ with $H$ being the class of a hyperplane in $\mathbb{P}^n$. Alternatively, we could look at actual points in $\mathbb{P}^n$ (the space we embed $X$ in) of the form $ap + bq$ for some $p, q \in \mathbb{P}^n$ and $(a : b) \in \mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: Please, choose which definition of a line you want to use and include it into the question. If you are going to use an embedding into $\mathbb{P}^n$, note that the result will depend on this choice.

Comment: If you define a line as a curve with class equal to the pullback of a line class on $\mathbb{P}^2$ then such a curve is exactly the pullback of a line from $\mathbb{P}^2$.

Comment: Looking at the original question and reference del Pezzo surface, it looks like I should have defined a line as the class of a curve $C$ in $\text{Pic } X$ such that $C \cdot H = 1$ with $H$ being the class of a hyperplane in $\mathbb{P}^n$. This is indicated in a second edit.

Comment: With this definition lines are parameterized by the so-called Hilbert scheme of lines, which significantly depends on the choice of a projective embedding (e.g., for $X = \mathbb{P}^2$ in its standard embedding the Hilbert scheme is isomorphic to the (dual) $\mathbb{P}^2$, and for the Veronese embedding it is empty).

Comment: In that case, is there a natural embedding into projective space of a blowup $\text{Bl}_{p_1, \ldots, p_r} \mathbb{P}^2$ similar to the canonical embedding in some way as in the side question? Also, what would be the smallest $n$ such that this blowup embeds into $\mathbb{P}^n$?

Comment: I am sure that much is known about the ample cone of such surfaces, but I am not an expert in this.

Comment: I understand. I'll try looking into what you mentioned.